# Prevent FluentValidation from applying value type validators on all methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have something like this validator:

```
public class SomeOtherValidator : AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public SomeOtherValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).Must(x => x.StartsWith("bar"));
    }
}
```

And a *whole bunch* of validators for reference types, e.g. of this kind:

```
public class UserDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<UserDto>
{
    public UserDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

I tried to bootstrap FluentValidation using this code in Startup:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddFluentValidation(c => c.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<UserDtoValidator>())
```

But now string arguments for *all* methods get validated by `SomeOtherValidator`:

```
[HttpGet("by-name/{name}")]
public ActionResult<UserDto> GetByName(string name)
{
    // TODO: Actual GET logic here
    return Ok(new UserDto { Name = name, Remarks = "dummy result" });
}

[HttpGet("by-thing/{thing}")]
public ActionResult<UserDto> GetByThing(string thing)
{
    if (!new SomeOtherValidator().Validate(thing).IsValid) return Conflict("Can't start with bar!");
    // TODO: Actual GET logic here
    return Ok(new UserDto { Name = thing, Remarks = "dummy result" });
}
```

This all makes sense, but I want to prevent validators for value types (`int`, `bool`, etc) and `string` from being used for automatic ModelState validation, *without* loosing the option to auto-register all other validators.

### What I've tried (1)

I've used some language magic to solve the issue:

```
public class ThingInfo
{
    public string Thing { get; private set; }
    public static implicit operator ThingInfo(string s) => new ThingInfo { Thing = s };
}

public class SomeOtherValidator : AbstractValidator<ThingInfo>
{
    public SomeOtherValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).Must(x => x.Thing.StartsWith("bar"));
    }
}
```

This allows me to keep asking for `string` arguments in controller methods, and pass them in where `ThingInfo` is being requested. But this has two major downsides:

- I need such a wrapper class for each validator of strings, ints, bools, etc.
- The intellisense for `new SomeOtherValidator().Validate(...)` will suggest a `ThingInfo` is requested, with no hint that you can pass in a `string` as well

### What I've tried (2)

I've also tried using this:

```
AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssemblyContaining<UserDtoValidator>()
    .ForEach(pair =>
    {
        var canBeAutoRegistered =
            typeof(IValidator).IsAssignableFrom(pair.InterfaceType)
            && pair.InterfaceType.IsGenericType
            && pair.InterfaceType.GenericTypeArguments.Single() != typeof(string)
            && pair.InterfaceType.GenericTypeArguments.Single().IsValueType != true;

        // Don't register IValidator<string> globally, or all string properties
        // of classes will always get that validator.
        if (canBeAutoRegistered)
            services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(
                pair.InterfaceType,
                pair.ValidatorType
            ));
    });
```

This also sort of works, but it seems very fragile, is a lot of code for a small thing, and I worry it forgets about many edge cases.

### What I've considered (3)

I guess I could simplify option 2 by using empty marker interfaces (e.g. `IAutoRegisterableValidator`) and use that to simplify the lambda...

---

Bottom line: is there some idiomatic way in FluentValidation with ASP.NET Core to do this, or should I stick with one of the above?

---

PS. The above is a *minimal* repro, but there's also [a gist with a *runnable* version of that code](https://gist.github.com/jeroenheijmans/bfc3d2bc41f23504313bd4da56be127c)